# Can't upload large files through PHP script even after editing php.ini

Tags: php, file-upload, apache2, vps

I have Ubuntu installed with LAMP stack (PHP5 and Apache2) on my VPS. My file upload script works perfectly on local, but it won't upload the same 8MB FLV file on the linode. It returns "Empty file". It does accept FLV files under 3MB and JPEGs with no problem.

Here is how I edited the `php.ini` file:

```
max_execution_time = 700

max_input_time = 700

memory_limit = 128M

post_max_size = 110M

file_uploads = On

upload_max_filesize = 105M

mysql.connect_timeout = 60
```

My script sets this variable for max file size: $max_file_size = 102537*1024; //max file upload size (bytes)

I have rebooted the VPS each time the php.ini file is changed. Still I get an "Empty file" when I try to upload the 8MB FLV file. By the way, I am editing the php.ini file under /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini and confirmed with a php info file that this is the correct file.

Would appreciate any help or advice.

Comment: What you give us is correct. You are looking at the wrong place.

Comment: looks ok also to me. You may confirm with small file uploads that you can upload from place "a" to place"b". If not, network checks.. ?

Comment: @hometbuzz: how do you do a network check? Small file uploads confirm that they go from place a to b just fine. It's just the bigger files above 3MB that return "empty".

Comment: after a week of searching, i finally solved. in my case was /tmp folder. His size was 1MB and i used following command `sudo umount /tmp`

Answer (score 0):

You may check configuration in Apache httpd.conf, it has a option called LimitRequestBody.

The html side may also limit the size

Please check it.